# Funciones en Kotin

Tags: kotlin

**1.1 Tamaño de un String

Descripción

Escribe un programa que llame a una función que imite la propiedad .length de la clase String.

Entrada:
Por la entrada recibirá un String.

Salida:
La salida debe ser el tamaño de String.**

Voy muy perdido en programación y en clase han explicado el tema de las funciones en kotlin. Os he puesto el ejemplo no para que me lo solucioneis si no para que me expliqueís como son las funciones a vuestro parecer.

Comment: Las preguntas muy amplias y/o basadas en opiniones terminan [cerradas](/help/closed-questions). Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Las funciones son bloques o trozos de código agrupados que se tienen que llamar para que se ejecute. Están pensados para hacer operaciones repetitivas, aunque (no 
es muy correcto) algunos lo usan para agrupar código largo.   Como dices en el ejemplo, las funciones les puedes pasar parámetros(opcional) y que te devuelvan un resultado(también opcional). Cuando las usas es preferible que tengan un solo objetivo o resultado final en mente. EJemplos: printar un string,hacer sumas, insertar datos en una tabla de una base de datos.Etc.

Comment: Respecto a kotlin te dejo una referencia de ejemplos de como se usan en el lenguaje: https://www.w3schools.com/KOTLIN/kotlin_functions.php